# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, post

I am trying to send the Arry "Feld" to my Flask Backend but i get the error message "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined"

here is my ts file:

```js
import { GetApiService } from './../get-api.service';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sodoku',
  templateUrl: './sodoku.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sodoku.component.css']
})
export class SodokuComponent implements OnInit {
  feld = []
  public constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  createTable(){
    document.getElementById('start').remove();
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      for (let k = 0; k < 9; k++){
        const elemet = document.getElementById('Sodoku');
        const id = String(i) + '/' + String(k);
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = "text";
        input.maxLength = 1;
        input.style.textAlign = "center";
        input.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(185,185,185)";
        input.style.width = "75px";
        input.style.height = "75px";
        input.style.fontSize = "75px";
        input.id = id;
        input.style.gridColumn = String(k+1)
        input.style.gridRow = String(i + 1);
        if (k == 3 || k == 6){
          input.style.borderLeft = "5px solid";
        }
        if (i == 3|| i == 6){
          input.style.borderTop = "5px solid";
        }
        //newElement.appendChild(input)
        elemet.appendChild(input);
      }
    }
    const button = document.createElement('button')
    button.addEventListener('click', this.solve)
    button.innerHTML = "Solve";
    document.getElementById('Sodoku').appendChild(button)
  }
  solve(): void{
    var copyFeld = []
    for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
      copyFeld.push([])
      for(let k = 0; k < 9; k++){
        var cellvalaue = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(String(i)+ "/"+ String(k))).value;
        if (cellvalaue == undefined){
          copyFeld[i].push(0)
        }
        else{
          copyFeld[i].push(Number(cellvalaue))
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(copyFeld)
    this.feld = copyFeld
    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/',this.feld).toPromise().then(data =>{
      console.log(data['message'])
    })
  }
}
```

the function "solve" is called by a button which is created in the "createTable" function which is also called by an button in HTML

can someone find my mistake?
Thank you for ypur help

Comment: I think this.http is undefined that's the reason you are getting the error Cannot read property 'post' of undefined"

Comment: Can you share where you have called `this.solve()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

```js
button.addEventListener('click', this.solve)
```

When `button` is clicked, it will call your component's `solve` method with `this` set to the button element instance rather than your component instance. (You can verify this by inspecting `this` inside your `solve` method when the method is invoked—it will likely be an HTMLButtonElement.)

However, within that method you need `this` to be a reference to your component instance because that component instance is what `http` is assigned to by Angular's dependency injection.

That's why you're getting the "Cannot read property 'post' of undefined" error because `this.http` will be `undefined` if `this` is your HTMLButtonElement rather than your component class.

There are two ways you can solve this:

You can explicitly [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the event listener context to your component instance:

```js
button.addEventListener('click', this.solve.bind(this))
```

That will force `this` within your `solve` method to be your component instance.

Or you can configure the event listener as an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
button.addEventListener('click', () => this.solve())
```

This will cause `this` within `solve` to be whatever `this` was where the event listener was attached, which is your component instance.

Comment: Thank you for your help now i understand it

Comment: @JonasB, that's great! Glad it helped. If you find this answered your question, please accept it as the answer so others who have the same question know. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for details.